# parameterizing the values to filter pandas rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.X.

This is my code currently:

```py
data1 = data[(data.id_x == 'B9') | (data.id_x == 'A12')]
```

I would like to parameterize this so these values can be passed in through a configuration file.

How do I do this?

Comment: `def filter(data, id_list): return data[data.id_x.isin(id_list)].copy()` and then call `filter(data, ['B9', 'A12'])`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please add this as an answer?